# Windows 7 Command Prompt: Typing android.bat returns java.exe options

Tags: java, android, windows-7, dos

When I type android or android.bat in the Windows Command Prompt as Administrator, I return the java.exe options not the android.bat options.

For example:

C:>android.bat
[INFO] Starting Android SDK and AVD Manager
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)

where options include:
    -client       to select the "client" VM
    -server       to select the "server" VM

When I cd to anywhere in the path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk-windows\tools - I do get the android options.

My system path is set to: `%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin;%ANDROID_SDK_PATH%\tools;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\SWTOOLS\ReadyApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lenovo\Access Connections\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\`

- %ANDROID_SDK_PATH% is set to:
  C:\Program Files
  (x86)\Android\android-sdk-windows
- %JAVA_HOME% is set to: C:\Program
  Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_23

How do I get the correction options returned for android.bat anywhere in my system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your java classpath to that folder as well, IIRC. Also consider the 'libs' folder within tools.

I'd suggest adding C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools to your path.